# Jquery slider dont work properly on chrome (android)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I have standard jQuery slider on website

```
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
<div id="slider-range-min">
```

and standard jQuery css file. But on mobile device I can't slide the slider. I can only click on slider bar and adjust values but handle don't work